# why I can't access my 3rd level CoreData data in swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

I have this model:

[image]

And In one of my ViewController classes I created a method with 3 do while loops (a nested loop) where I insert all the "cursos", "temas" and "subtemas" to populate all my coreData model.

So, inside that method I put this loop to access a part of my coreData data to see if my nested loop work, I did it like this:

```
    var i = cursos.count
    var index = 0


    do{

        println(cursos[index].nombre)
        println(cursos[index].temas[0].nombre)
        println(cursos[index].temas[0].subTemas[0].nombre)

        index++
    }while(index < i)
```

"cursos" is my NSManaged object array containing all my "cursos", so in that last loop I think I access the "subTema" data of my first "curso" with the first "tema".

Well, everything went like I want, but When I tried to access the same data in another class (my original goal: have access to my data anywhere), my method to access the data don't recognised my "subTemas" stack of NSManagedObjects linked to my other two stacks of NSManagedObjects. Example:

[image]

Maybe I need to access my data in another way, through my relationships perhaps? if that so, how can I do it? I really need your help, thanks !

Update: My NSManagedObjects Subclasses generated by Xcode:

Curso.swift

```
 import Foundation
 import CoreData

 class Curso: NSManagedObject {

 @NSManaged var msjBienvenida: String
 @NSManaged var nombre: String
 @NSManaged var nombrePng: String
 @NSManaged var temas: NSOrderedSet

    }
```

Tema.swift

```
  import Foundation
  import CoreData

  class Tema: NSManagedObject {

  @NSManaged var nombre: String
  @NSManaged var curso: Curso
  @NSManaged var subTemas: NSOrderedSet

  }
```

SubTema.swift

```
 import Foundation
 import CoreData

 class SubTema: NSManagedObject {

 @NSManaged var nombre: String
 @NSManaged var tema: Tema

 }
```

Update 2 (relevant code for MartinR):

Inside the VC where I will make a web service call to fill my coreData data, here I don't have to cast my arrays, I can access my data like cursos[index].temas[0].subtemas[ 1 ].name , why ? :

```
  func webServiceCall2(index:Int){


   var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

   var exeWebServiceCall2 = defaults.objectForKey("exeWebServiceCall2") as? Bool

    if (exeWebServiceCall2 == true){

    var temasArray:[String] = ["Word","PowerPoint","Excel"]
    var subTemasArray: [String] = ["Introduccion","Tema 1","Tema 2"," Tema 3"]

    //Guardar temas y subtemas adquiridos de mi web service a mi grafo de objetos de coreData
    var cantidadCursos = cursos.count
    var indexCursos = 0
    var cantidadTemas = temasArray.count
    var indexTemas = 0
    var cantidadSubTemas = subTemasArray.count
    var indexSubTemas = 0


      var error: NSError?

    do{//para cada uno de mis cursos
        var cursoActual = cursos[indexCursos]

        do{//agregar un objeto entity Tema(que contiene un arreglo con los temas)

        let temaEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tema", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        let temaActual = Tema(entity: temaEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        temaActual.nombre = temasArray[indexTemas]

            //Inserto todos los temas a mi curso Actual
            var temas = cursoActual.temas.mutableCopy() as NSMutableOrderedSet
            temas.addObject(temaActual)
            cursoActual.temas = temas.copy() as NSOrderedSet

                 do{

                let subTemaEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("SubTema", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
                let subTemaActual = Tema(entity: subTemaEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
                subTemaActual.nombre = subTemasArray[indexSubTemas]

                //Inserto todos los subTemas a mi tema Actual
                var subTemas = temaActual.subTemas.mutableCopy() as NSMutableOrderedSet
                subTemas.addObject(subTemaActual)
                temaActual.subTemas = subTemas.copy() as NSOrderedSet

                    //Guardar, aunque no estoy seguro si puedo usar el mismo managedContext que ya tenia
                    if !managedContext.save(&error)
                      {
                            println("No pude guardar: \(error)")
                      }

                       indexSubTemas++
                    }while(indexSubTemas < cantidadSubTemas)

               //reset index subtemas  y aumento indexTemas para el siguiente ciclo de temas
              indexSubTemas = 0
             indexTemas++
           }while(indexTemas < cantidadTemas)
        //reset index temas  y aumento indexCursos para el siguiente ciclo de cursos
        indexTemas = 0
        indexCursos++
    }while(indexCursos < cantidadCursos)


        defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "exeWebServiceCall2")
        defaults.synchronize()


    }


}
```

Comment: What do your NSManagedObject subclasses look like (Curso.swift, Tema.swift, SubTema.swift)? Did you write them yourself or are they generated by Xcode?

Comment: @MartinR The subclasses are generated by Xcode, I updated with images of my classes, thanks !

Comment: @MartinR ok, I will update the post again, sorry

Comment: `subTemas` is a plain `NSOrderedSet` so swift can't know that item `[0]` is of type `SubTema`. You could use `as` to cast but I'm assuming that Xcode has some means to generate a class with a typed collection that would be the proper answer. I've not used Swift and Core Data together yet so I'll have to decline to try to produce it.

Comment: MartinR I updated the post with the code, and @Tommy I will try to use "as" but I think like you that it has to be another way, besides, why In my method where I populate my core data, Xcode did not mark any error? It's so confusing X,x XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `temas` property is a `NSOrderedSet`, and the subscript `[0]` returns the
type `AnyObject`. So (as already said in a comment) you have to cast the `AnyObject`
to the actual type

```
let curso = cursos[index]
println(curso.nombre)
let firstTema = curso.temas[0] as Tema
println(firstTema.nombre)
let firstSubTema = firstTema.subTemas[0] as SubTema
println(firstSubTema.nombre)
```

Note that you can simplify your loop using `for - in`:

```
for curso in cursos {
    // ...
}
```

and recursively enumerating all objects would look like

```
for curso in cursos {
    println(curso.nombre)

    for tema in curso.temas.array as [Tema] {
        println(tema.nombre)

        for subtema in tema.subTemas.array as [SubTema] {
            println(subtema.nombre)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MartinN, it works : ) , just one more thing, do you know why in my method where I fill my CoreData I did not have to cast my NSManagedObjects?

Comment: I updated my post, with the code I think is the relevant code for my question, thanks! @MartinR

Comment: @JuanVillalvazo: That is a lot of code, but I cannot see where you call `cursos[index].temas[0].subtemas[ 1 ].name` in that part. – Actually I would suggest that you post a new question. Then more people will see (and possibly answer) it.

Comment: ok maybe its for the best to post a new question : ) thank you so much @MartinR ! and by the way, I forgot that I erase that part of the code but just after the giant loop (I need to simplified that loop xD) I can put an println(cursos[index].temas[0].subtemas[ 1 ].name)  with out the need to cast it.