# Swift throws compilation error on Fetching objects in file other than AppDelgate and accessing element in NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I have a CoreDataManager.Swift where I delegated the creation of PersistentStore Coordinator, ManagedObjectContext and NSManagedObjectModel

I have the following function where Entity is a NSManagedObject and timeStamps is NSOrderedSet. In data model timeStamps is one to many relationship to another NSManagedObject TimeStamp

```
func fetchData(){
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Entity")

    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults =
    CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
        error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

    //If error then return...

    for entity in fetchedResults as! [Entity]
    {
        println(entity.name)
        println(entity.timeStamps)
        for eS in entity.timeStamps
        {
            println(eS.time) //OK in AppDelegate but throw compilation error in CoreDataManager.swift
        // Error thrown is AnyObject does not have a member name time
        //If I force to TimeStamp then the fault on timeStamps is not fired.


        }
    }
}
```

The issues is, it works fine if I have that function in AppDelegate but throws compilation errors in CoreDataManager. If I try to force it as TimeStamp then the fault on timeStamps is not fired.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What compilation errors, exactly?

Comment: Could be the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930542/why-i-cant-access-my-3rd-level-coredata-data-in-swift. In that problem, casting the elements of the NSOrderedSet to the actual managed object subclass was necessary (but not everywhere, and I did not figure out why).

Comment: @Tom: See the commented lines of code for error. @ Martin: As I mentioned, when I cast it; it comes out as fault and the fault is not fired automatically.